# Maven - rename third party jar at install

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to install `org.apache.commons.io` into my application, version 1.4. Now, I am using Equinox/P2 to manage my installations which creates a bundles.info file. In the main application there are some checks written which checks for version numbers, especially the format which should be `major.minor.micro`. But in my case I only have 1.4.

I want to append a '0' to the jar file of `commons.io` using pom so that it will be 1.4.0. So when I perform `mvn clean install`, it should install 1.4.0 in my target-platform as well as my local maven repo. Also it should modify the bundles.info accordingly.

Any ideas how?

Thanks.

Comment: You could create a fork of the 1.4 release and install it as 1.4.0. Then pull in that version.

Comment: If I correctly remember you can get a jar with it's version into OSGi and use it but I would not recommend to shade it etc. Furthermoe commons.io is already an OSGi bundle....

Answer (score 0):

You use [maven shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to include classes from jar in your new jar. You could define any name and version in your pom.xml.

Other option is like @Dan W said, [fork it from github](https://github.com/apache/commons-io) and modify pom.xml and build the jar.